# file reading in python

Tags: python, file, config

I need to read the file like below:

```
config = {
    'name': 'hello',
    'see?': 'world'
}
```

using keys like name and see? ,but I don't want to hard code the values in script.And how to deal with more deep nesting in this case.The file may contain more sections like this how can I recognize that 'name' belongs to which section at runtime.

Comment: I do not understand your question. Can you please provide an example of a config file and the data-structure you want to get from it?

Comment: read file with this config? what is this config? you want open file, not big deal

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/186916/configuration-file-with-list-of-key-value-pairs-in-python

Comment: If a particular answer solves your problem, accept it using the tick on the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you encode your structure as JSON data, as I think you want and you did in the example, you just need to write and read the structure in a file.
As an example:

```
 import json 
 config = {
  'name': 'hello',
  'see?': 'world'
 }
 out = open('config.json','w')
 out.write(json.dumps(config))
 out.close()
```

Configuration file saved

```
 input = open('config.json','r')
 config = json.loads(input.read())
 input.close()
 print config
```

Configuration file reloaded

Answer (score 3):

That file looks like valid python. If you can rename it `file.py` You could just use:

```
from file import config
print config['name']
print config['see?']
```

Otherwise, the file could be JSON. See http://docs.python.org/library/json.html

Comment: I'd go for the json rather than reading as python. Much safer, and will produce catchable errors rather than failing with parse errors.

Comment: @Phil H: The example is Python.  Importing Python with configuration parameters is perfectly safe and reports perfectly debuggable errors.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a config file? Has the format been defined already or are you creating it? If you just need to read options from a file there's:

http://docs.python.org/library/configparser.html

which handles the INI format. If you already have a file in the format above can you tell if it's a JSON format? If so there's a module for that too.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your config format is either valid python or JSON, which has a built-in parser in python. See http://docs.python.org/library/json.html for more information. If you're trying to import a valid python file as config just use `import`.